# ubuntu emulator image and sdk 15.04

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, sdk

I'm developing an application using the sdk 15.04 but i tried all the images available on the emulator and cant find one with that sdk installed and for that reason i can not run my app on the emulator. I have used the stable and rc channels for both i386 and armhf archs.

I always can back to sdk 14.10 but i want to stay in the latest as much as possible.

How do i can install the latest sdk on a emulator device or what image should i use.

Any advice please.

Thanks.